# Importing an .fcp file into FCPX

Tags: final-cut-pro, final-cut-pro-x

A friend of mine created our wedding video in FCP and now that I've got the project I've been trying to import it into the trial copy of FCPX (off the App Store) but it doesn't like it.

I've read on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Cut_Pro) that FCPX doesn't support FCP file formats, so what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Export your FCP project as a self-contained quick time video file.
Then import the QT file into X.
You'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it but "7toX" can import FCP7 projects into FCP X:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/7tox-for-final-cut-pro/id496926258?mt=12

Answer (score -1):

Open any 20y old PSD file with the latest version of PhotoshopCC on either windows or Mac - yes. Open any 10y old FCP file on a the latest version of FinalCut X on Mac - no. The developers best suited to address the issue - don't.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot do anything, from what I understand they have added xml support so you may be able to import an xml from fcp7 but why, fcpx is awful, stay in fcp7

Comment: Not really an useful answer, as previous answers clearly show that there are ways to accomplish this.

Comment: No it is usefull, exporting a quicktime of your cut does not allow you to continue editing...fcpx is not a good program, i told him to try xml, however like I said before if you can keep fcp7 and use that, post houses are not fcpx compatible for this exact reason

Comment: Ok, but what about the "7toX" program? I haven't tried it, but that might work right? Saying "You cannot do anything" and "fcpx is awful" is not really helpful and does not add to the quality of this site.

Comment: 7toX is the XML support for FCPX, however with FCPX you are going to be limited to having to buy updates to a software that is far from a pro-video editing software, I am trying to do the OP a favor by saving him headaches in the future by avoiding using FCPX all together, premiere is a much more pro software, and the old FCP 7 is also better, sure it looks nice, but it is not the way to learn how to edit...but when FCPX first came out, there was NO WAY to import an edit from FCP7 to FCPX, you cant make up a way to do it, it just didnt work